# java.lang.NoSuchFieldException android studio?

Tags: java, android, stack, trace

I am creating a JSONRequest, basically, I keep getting this stack trace when refreshing does anyone know what is causing this?

> /EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
>   E/EnterpriseKnoxManager: Failed at EnterpriseContainerManager API getEnterpriseContainerManager 
>                                                         java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: Container with Id 1 does not exists
>                                                             at com.sec.enterprise.knox.EnterpriseContainerManager.(EnterpriseContainerManager.java:706)
>                                                             at com.sec.enterprise.knox.EnterpriseKnoxManager.getEnterpriseContainerManager(EnterpriseKnoxManager.java:319)
>                                                             at com.sec.knox.containeragent.core.ContainerServiceAdapter.getInstance(ContainerServiceAdapter.java:55)
>                                                             at com.sec.knox.containeragent.app.util.ContainerNotification.updateModechangeNotification(ContainerNotification.java:158)
>                                                             at com.sec.knox.containeragent.service.notification.EnterpriseNotificationCenter$5.onReceive(EnterpriseNotificationCenter.java:1012)
>                                                             at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:768)
>                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                             at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:1866)

Comment: Can you show the code where you are creating the JSON request?

Comment: Well, I have two different JSONrequests, one gets information and one deletes information. In my fragment I have the JSONrequest to get the information and in  my adapter I have the request to delete information. I was thinking that this might be the cause of the error is this possible?